# How do I define an implicit typecast from my class to a scalar?

Tags: c++, class, implicit, casting, scalar

I have the following code, which uses a Unicode string class from a library that I'm writing:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "ucpp"
main() {
  ustring a = "test";
  ustring b = "ing";
  ustring c = "- -";
  ustring d;
  d = "cafe\xcc\x81";
  printf("%s\n", (a + b + c[1] + d).encode());
}
```

The encode method of the ustring class instances converts the internal Unicode into a UTF-8 char *. However, because I don't have access to the char class definition, I am unsure on how I can define an implicit typecast (so that I don't have to manually call encode when using with printf, etc).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, I would recommend that you consider not providing an implicit conversion. You may find that the situations where unexpected conversions are not caught as errors outweighs the cost of calling `encode` when you want a `char*`.

If you do decide to provide an implicit conversion you declare it like this (inside your class definition.

```
operator char*();
```

You might be able to make the method const, in which case you can use:

```
operator char*() const;
```

Usually you would also want to return a pointer to a non-modifiable buffer:

```
operator const char*() const;
```

In the body of your function you should `return` an appropriate pointer. As an implicit conversion clients wouldn't expect to have to free the returned buffer so if you need to make a special buffer for your return value you will have to maintain a pointer to this buffer until a suitable point to free it. Typically such a suitable moment might be the next mutating operation on your class object.

Note that as `printf` takes any number and type of optional arguments you would still need to cast your class object in any case.

```
printf("%s\n", static_cast<const char*>(a + b + c[1] + d));
```

or

```
printf("%s\n", (const char*)(a + b + c[1] + d));
```

Both of these are more verbose than an explicit call to `encode`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. I will think about the pros/cons and test out whether an implicit is really beneficial.

Comment: (Sorry about not accepting your answer yet; SO is limiting my acceptance frequency so I have to wait a few minutes)

Comment: @Delan Azabani: You don't have to accept answers straight away; it's fine to wait an see if someone comes up with a better answer that mine.

Comment: For string classes especially, an implicit conversion to `char*` is very problematic. Even something simple as `str[i]` will now probably become ambiguous. Similar for `c ? str : "foo"`.

Comment: The implicit conversion will not be invoked for `printf` in the first place, because this function accepts any type you throw at it. So you are already losing the battle...

Comment: @UncleBens: I never realised that! Hmm... maybe the implicit would be invoked when using puts()?

Comment: @UncleBens: Good point about this particular situation; I'll add to my answer.

Comment: For outputting, isn't it better to provide the relevant ostream overrides, rather than using C-style I/O functions? (I'm a C++ noob)

Comment: @dreamlax: I think one would definitely expect a C++ string class to overload `<<` and `>>` (and getline).

Comment: One other alternative is to let it implicitly convert by doing `printf("%s\n", +(a + b + c[1] + d));`

Comment: @litb: I hadn't thought of that. Yes, it would be less verbose but in itself it looks like another strong argument against an implicit conversion :) .